# ajax search says " no suggestions " all the time

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to make a Live search to show business owner user names, here is my code :

PHP File " f_searchBoForAd.php "

```
include('functions_cp/f_connection.php');
sqlconnection();

$getName_sql = 'SELECT * FROM businessowner
WHERE businessOwnerUserName LIKE "%' . $searchq .'%"';
$getName = mysql_query($getName_sql) or die (mysql_error());

$a=mysql_fetch_array($getName);

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_POST["q"];

//lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
    if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint=$a[$i];
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
        }
      }
    }
  }

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint == "")
  {
  $response="no suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;
```

Javascript File, ajax_framework.js

```
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","f_searchBoForAd.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

the result of my html form says " no suggestions " all time , where is the problem ?

Comment: where does $searchq come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some problems on PHP code:

1. You are only looking at the first result returned from the SQL query, where you should be looping the results with code like this:

   ```
   while($a=mysql_fetch_array($getName)) {
       // do something with each row, which is $a
   }
   ```

   The way you have it, you are actually looping the columns on the first row (looping with `for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)`, and looking for values in `$a[$i]`)
2. On the SQL query, you look for records that *contain* the terms searched, surrounded by anything (`LIKE "%' . $searchq .'%"'`). Then, on the PHP loop, you seem to be checking for records that *begin with* the search terms, here:

   `if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))`)

   You could do that in the SQL query itself, by using `LIKE "' . $searchq .'%"'`
3. Also on the SQL part, you seem to be using `$searchq` before it's declared or assigned a value. Before you build the SQL query, you should have something like this:

   ```
   $searchq = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q']);
   ```

   Otherwise, your query will return all rows from the db table.

Answer (score 1):

In `f_searchBoForAd.php`, things are not happening in the right order. Consider this process:

1. Get the search parameter from the query string
2. Sanitize search parameter so your database doesn't get hacked into
3. Query the database for suggestions
4. Return results, if any

Taking that into consideration, your basic php would look like this:

```
    $q=mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['q']) ? $_POST['q'] : false);

    if (strlen($q) < 1)
        die('Invalid query');

    $getName_sql = '
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            businessowner 
        WHERE 
            businessOwnerUserName LIKE "%' . $q .'%"
    ';
    $getName = mysql_query($getName_sql) or die ('Database error:'.mysql_error());

    $output = '';
    while ($results_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getName)) {
        // assemble your results here... 
        $output .= '<span>'.$results_row['name'].'</span>';
    }
   die($output);
```

Also, when you query the database, you should specify which fields to fetch rather than using `SELECT *...`. If you need the id and the name, use `SELECT id, name...` - that way your code is explicit to someone else or yourself in the future, and you can easily debug unexpected results. If you use `*`, your result might not contain a field that your code uses. If you specify the fields and one of the fields you expect is not there, you'll get a database error on the query that explains exactly what happened.